# Refreshing a Google Token using Google REST API in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm wondering if anyone has solved managing the expiration of Google OAuth2 tokens?

The example below is a REST call to get a list of calendars with a valid token.  If the token is expired, I will get a 401 response and need to refresh the token using the 'refresh token' stored in my database.  I'm wondering if anyone has a strategy around this for their web application?

```
     var httpContent = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList");
            httpContent.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + token);
            responseBody = client.SendAsync(httpContent).Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

I've thought about refreshing automatically upon user logging in and saving the refresh token encrypted in session, but not sure if there are any better strategies.

//Notes
Strategy Options:

1 - Upon Logging a user in, refresh all OAuth tokens for user.  This works assuming that a session will never last longer than a token timeout period. (may not be reliable for all OAuth servers).

2 - When refreshing, use token expiration to record expiration date/time in database.  Before calling any API, check if token needs to be refreshed.  (still need to account for edge case where token expires unexpectedly outside of normal expiration schedule)

3 - Catch the response status of the call and check for 401s.  If receive a 401, refresh the token and try again.  This could be a fail-over for both Options 1/2.  Code for this example would be here:

```
  var restClient = new RestClient();
        var request = new RestRequest("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList", Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + token);

        // execute the request
        var response = restClient.Execute(request);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            var newToken = RefreshGoogleToken(token);
            request = new RestRequest("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList", Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + newToken);

            // execute the request
            response = restClient.Execute(request);
        }
        var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
        dynamic responseJson = JsonValue.Parse(content);

        var calendarList = new List<GoogleCalendar>();
        foreach (var item in responseJson.items)
        {
            var calendar = new GoogleCalendar { Kind = item.kind, Etag = item.etag, Id = item.id, Title = item.summary, Description = item.description, Location = item.location, Timezone = item.timeZone, SummaryOverride = item.summaryOverride, ColorId = item.colorId, AccessRole = item.accessRole };
            if (item.defaultReminders != null)
            {
                calendar.DefaultReminders = new List<GoogleCalendarReminder>();
                foreach (var reminder in item.defaultReminders)
                {
                    var rem = new GoogleCalendarReminder { Method = reminder.method, Minutes = reminder.minutes };
                    calendar.DefaultReminders.Add(rem);
                }
            }

            calendarList.Add(calendar);
        }

        return calendarList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the expiration time is known you can keep track of your token's expiration time and anticipate that it has already expired, then just do the refresh at that time.

I would imagine you could also simply respond to the 401 errors with a refresh as well, and even as a fail safe if the expiration tracking happens to fail (just be sure to add code to avoid getting stuck in a loop).